# Open a new tab with javascript but stay on current tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Is it possible to open a new tab in browser using the `window.open("http://www.google.com");` function, but open it in the background and remain on the current page?
When i Click in hyperlink the page will same but link will open in new tab...

I try this solution but it work only in Firefox [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213807/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab)
but I want to do in all browsers.

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplication to me. This question is specific for the keeping the current tab [window] in the foreground, not tab vs window.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/59509486/1916821 is one of possible tricks to solve this issue

Comment: Absolutely not a duplicate. Such BS. Who "reviewed" it and decided to keep it closed?

Answer (score 8):

As confirmed in both: [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213807/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab)
[source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

there isn't a function that works throughout all browsers. There are options for popups, but this isn't a good idea as many use popup blockers.

To reiterate the first source, it's a browser setting for each user to decide to open a new tab in the background, or not. And because users decide this in their browser settings you will get inconsistent experiences.

Comment: I searched for ~60 minutes on the topic of opening a non-focused new tab and this is the only true valid answer on this topic as of November 2017!

Comment: You say _for each user to decide to open a new tab in the background_ but if I write JavaScript for my use then I still cannot choose to keep the current tab active when I open a new tab (window). So users cannot make the decision.

Answer (score 3):

Try following may be helpful

```
<button id="open">open</button>

document.getElementById('open').onclick = function() {
    window.open('http://google.com');   
};
```

**Note:**
You can't open tabs in the background using javascript because this is set in the user's preferences in about:config, which you have no control over. The setting in about:config in Firefox is:

**It is only possible if you will be generate the Click event with Already Pressed Control Key Dynamically.**

e.g. Ctrl + Click will always open new tab and stay you on current tab.

> browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground=true

Answer (score -9):

try this code

```
 window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Comment: this doesnt solve the question ... it opens but loses focus