# Javascript: window.open in a new tab but without switching

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using Firefox 51.0.1 and I have the "When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately" option disabled.

But when I make a window.open(url, '_blank'), it does open in a new tab correctly, but it also switch to it immediately. I would like to avoid the last part.

It seems like the Firefox option above is for links clicked from the browser but not for links opened from a JS event.

Is there a way I can do that, an advance option?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278498/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab-using-javascript

Comment: Sounds like it might be a security concern. This would allow malicious sites to load in ads and phishing sites in the background without you noticing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a new tab with javascript but stay on current tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278498/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab-using-javascript)