# window.open focus on the first page

Tags: javascript

How to open a URL in a new tab using javascript without focus on the page you just opened.

For example the following code is placed on the `index.html` page.

```
<button onclick="link()">Click here</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function link() {
    window.open('pages.html');
}
</script>
```

When the button is clicked, it will open a new tab, but focus directly on `page.html` page.

How to focus on the `index.html` page?

Comment: Why? Whats the usecase?

Comment: Whether a new window opens in a new tab instead, and whether a new tab steals focus or not, are browser settings. You can't influence those with JS.

Comment: So that those who click do not directly know it

Comment: as far as I know, it configured within the browser. you can try to call focus() right after the link() or in this function

Comment: @Tamar How is the code example?

Comment: SO is the best place to ask how to screw with users...

Answer (score 0):

It'll either be a configuration setting in your browser or simply not possible.

Please take a look at these similar answers:

- [Open a new tab with javascript but stay on current tab using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278498/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab-using-javascript)
- [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)