# open new tab with router-link but stay at the current tab

Tags: vue.js

How to open a new windows with router-link, **but stay at the same page**, something like, (right-click -> open in new tab), so when I click on the link, it will open a new tab, but not take me to the new tab, I wanna stay at the current tab. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a problem with Vue, please check this links

[source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278498/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab-using-javascript) --- [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213807/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab) --- [source3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Regards!