# open new window or tab but keep focus in the current

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I want to open new window or tab, but  I want to keep focus  in the current window. I currently use the following code :

```
window.open('/Pages/FilesDownload.aspx?q=' + args._commandArgument, '_blank');
```

what is the modification I must do to in the code?

Comment: I don't believe you can control this behaviour in Javascript, as it is down to the users' settings in the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213807/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab