# <a target="_blank"> onlick should open a new tab but the focus should be on current tab and not on the new tab and should work on chrome and mozzila

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I've tried jquery window.open, but all focus will be shifted to new tab, and i dont want that,  onclick should open new tab without shifting focus from current tab, also tried `window.blur()` and `window.focus()`, but doesn't fit my requirement.

Comment: Possible dubplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213807/open-a-new-tab-with-javascript-but-stay-on-current-tab

Comment: Your duplicate answer was an old school that not working anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tab behaviour is controlled by the browser.

You wont have any way of controlling it from javascript.

Being able to control that kind of behaviour would be a serious security concern.

Comment: i've seen some websites while we click on download, opens a new tab but focus is still on current tab. is there any way to do so?

Comment: its not possible.