# JS how to open new tab multiple times in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, window

How can I open multiple times new tab in chrome using window.open with for loop?

example:

```
const openFollowedProfiles = () => {
    for (const profile of store.followed){
        console.log(profile)
        window.open(profile, '_blank');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to security reasons, you can't open multiple windows at once.

Each time you want to create a new window you must get user's interaction with a site ("click" event for example).

Comment: So. There are no any other option to do this from js with calling only one function?

Comment: No, you are required to have user interaction. Otherwise troll sites would open dozens of tabs at the same time.